# How to change total div when i select an option in Angular

Tags: angular

app.component.html:

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <div class="form-group type">
    <div class="group">
      <label  class="input-label" for="type" >Select Type<span class="text-danger pl-1">*</span>
      </label><br>
      <select class="form-control decorated" name="role" id="type" >
        <option value="">Select the type</option>
        <option value="option1" >option1</option>
        <option value="option2">option2</option>
        <option value="option3">option3</option>
        <option value="other">Other</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div>1</div>
<div>2</div>
<div>3</div>
```

If I select `option1` then I need to display 1st `div`. If I select the `option2` then I need to display 2nd `div`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
    <div class="form-group type">
        <div class="group">
            <label class="input-label" for="type">Select Type<span class="text-danger pl-1">*</span>
            </label><br>
            <select class="form-control decorated" name="role" id="type" 
                (change)="selectedValue = $event.target.value">
                <option value="">Select the type</option>
                <option value="option1">option1</option>
                <option value="option2">option2</option>
                <option value="option3">option3</option>
                <option value="other">Other</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedValue == 'option1'">1</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedValue == 'option2'">2</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedValue == 'option3'">3</div>

@Component({
    selector: 'app-dashboard',
    templateUrl: './dashboard.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./dashboard.component.css']
  })
  export class DashboardComponent implements OnInit {
    public selectedOption;
    constructor() { }
  
    ngOnInit(): void {}
  
  }
```

Comment: Please read [ask] and [edit] your question to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Answer (score 3):

You need a `selectedOption` property in your component which you bind to `ngModel` changes on the `<select>` element.

You then can bind this property to the `<div>` elements using `*ngIf`.

```html
<div class="d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
<div class="form-group type">
 <div  class="group">
   <label  class="input-label" for="type" >Select Type<span class="text-danger pl-1">*</span>
   </label><br>
   <select class="form-control decorated" name="role" id="type" [(ngModel)]="selectedOption">
     <option   value="">Select the type</option>
     <option   value="option1" >option1</option>
     <option   value="option2">option2</option>
     <option   value="option3">option3</option>
     <option   value="other">Other</option>
   </select>
 </div>
</div>

<div *ngIf="selectedOption === 'option1'">1</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedOption === 'option2'">2</div>
<div *ngIf="selectedOption === 'option3'">3</div>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  public selectedOption;
}
```

[StackBlitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q33njg?file=src/app/app.component.html)